# How not to exit node process when using readline-sync?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm creating a pomodoro timer with node.

At the moment I start the project as so `node start.js coding`

I let that run as I do my work. When I need a break I terminate the process and the time I've spent coding get's added into a JSON file as so

```
{
  "code": [
    {
      "seconds": 1,
      "time": "00 : 00 : 01",
      "date": "2020-06-28T03:08:42.340Z"
    }
  ],
  "read": [],
  "write": []
}
```

Now I'm just trying to think of things I'll need in the future, I'll most definitely forget the keys in the above object. Is it `code`, `coding`, `write`, `writing`? So I thought I'd have a prompt.

```
var objKeys = [...Object.keys(obj), 'info']
const inputVariable =  objKeys[readline.keyInSelect(objKeys, 'What are you going to be working on?')]
```

As it is, once I make the selection, the process terminates, **I don't want that**.

(I could make the selection when I want to actually terminate, but most likely that would be confusing)

Is there a way to make the selection and still keep the process running

**EDIT**

```
const time = require('./module/timeEntry');
var readline = require('readline-sync');
var obj = require('./data.json') // has the above json code
var start = process.hrtime(); // start the timer
var objKeys = Object.keys(obj)
const inputVariable =  objKeys[readline.keyInSelect(objKeys, 'Which task you're going to work on?')]
function exitHandler(options, exitCode) {
    if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
    if (exitCode || exitCode === 0) {
      //code
      if(inputVariable !== "info"){
        time.timeEntry(obj, start, inputVariable) // reads and writes to file
      }
      
    }
    if (options.exit) process.exit();
}
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true}));

// I want to be able to do this: `ctrl+c`
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit:true}));
```

The problem is the moment the `inputVariable` is entered by the user, the process ends.

`time.timeEntry(obj, start, inputVariable)` simply reads and writes some time keeping info into JSON.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var getTime = require('./getTime')

const timeEntry = (obj, start, segment ) => {
let totalSeconds = process.hrtime(start)[0];
  obj[segment].push({
        seconds: totalSeconds,
        time: getTime.getTime(totalSeconds),
        date: new Date
      })

  let data = JSON.stringify(obj);
  fs.writeFileSync('data.json', data , 'utf-8');
}
exports.timeEntry = timeEntry;
```

I don't need to use `readline-sync`, if I instead use `const inputVariable = process.argv[2]` and run `node start.js coding`, the process wouldn't be terminated which is what I want

Comment: Is there any code after that snippet? If that's the whole file, then indeed the process will end after it finishes executing.

Comment: @Alex there is. the entire code comes after that. Code which calculates the time passed, reading a JSON file, modifying the contents of the file (and so writing to it). It all works, but I don't want it to terminate.

Comment: I see; can you share some [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) portion of the code that comes after? Otherwise it will be difficult to analyze this further

Comment: @Alex I added more code - hope it's clear

Comment: So I ran into your similar problem, the solution I chose was to have an initialization script run. At the beginning of my main program I simply put in a stop if a flag hasn't been checked and gave a prompt to run the init script because I couldn't seem to find a viable way to avoid the command line from closing out. Years later but maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what's your code is doing right now:

- read in the `inputVariable` from the user
- *define* a function `exitHandler`
- tell Node to invoke `exitHandler` when the program exits
- tell Node to invoke `exitHandler` upon receiving `SIGINT`

Note that none of these steps involves *calling* `exitHandler`, or doing anything else for that matter (e.g. there's no code here that *waits* for anything to happen).

Perhaps the confusion is coming from the use of `process.on`: this function tells Node that *when* it receives `SIGINT` (e.g. you press Ctrl-C), *then* it should call `exitHandler`. In particular, this does *not* tell your program "pause execution until SIGINT is received". As a result, after calling `process.on`, your code "continues" but there's no more code to run so the process ends (before it can ever receive SIGINT).

It seems like you want your program to do nothing until the signal is received; in that case you could add

```
while (true) {}
```

or similar at the end. So your code will do nothing (forever), until it receives `SIGINT`, then it will call `exitHandler`.

Comment: If I remove `readline-sync` the program works the way I want it (do nothing till Ctrl-C). But  `readline-sync` ends the process. I don't want that. If I hardcode the value for `inputVariable` **then** everything work great (as you described). But `readline-sync`  doesn't let the program to wait for my Ctrl+C, but immediately terminates - I'm asking whether there's a way to prevent that.

Comment: Where should I add `while (true) {}`?

Comment: `while (true) {}` is worthless.  That just hangs the program and blocks the event loop so nothing can ever be called and the program can never do anything.  There's no point in that.  The program needs to be listening for some future event to stay alive - a timer, an open socket, an open server, etc...  It should have some reason to actually still be running.